# repeat volley call until the status is not 500

Tags: android, android-volley

I make call on a server, where there is a problem on a call at a current url. Sometimes it returns response code 500. With a second try it returns 200 and the data I want. I tried to make the call until the error will be different of `ServerError` but with no success.

```
do {
    JsonObjectRequest ownerDataRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            UserEventOwner userEventOwner = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), UserEventOwner.class);
            JsonParser.getEventCreatorDisplayName(context, userEventOwner, index);
            Log.i("owner", userEventOwner.getDisplayName());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            serverError = error;
            VolleyLog.d(tag, error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(ownerDataRequest, tag);

} while (serverError instanceof com.android.volley.ServerError);
```

how can I make the call until I'll get the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found a solution. I just make the call again on the `Response.ErrorListener()`

```
   ownerDataRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            UserEventOwner userEventOwner = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), UserEventOwner.class);
            JsonParser.getEventCreatorDisplayName(context, userEventOwner, index);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            serverError = error;
            VolleyLog.d(tag, error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(ownerDataRequest, tag);
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(ownerDataRequest, tag);
```